# Why does my Python 3.5 re.match() returns None while grep -e works?

Tags: python, svg

I'm trying to parse parts of an SVG file to get HEX fill colors (like #ceff80 etc)

When I do it with Bash `grep` command:

```
grep -o -e "fill:#[a-f, 0-9]*;" Sample.svg
```

Results are as follows:

```
fill:#000000;
fill:#ff0000;
fill:#ff9955;
fill:#ff9955;
fill:#ffffff;
fill:#ff0000;
fill:#800080;
fill:#666666;
fill:#666666;
fill:#00ff00;
```

But when I try it with Python's `re` module, I get `None`:

```
import re
color = re.match(r'fill:#[a-f, 0-9]*;', style)
```

This is invoked inside a loop that walks through the XML structure using `ElementTree`. The `style` string contains values like this:

```
font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;font-size:40px;line-height:125%;font-family:sans-serif;letter-spacing:0px;word-spacing:0px;display:inline;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:1px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1;filter:url(#filter5107)
```

I want to extract the fill:#xxxxxx; color to then truncate it with `[6:-1]` range expression for further processing.

For some reason it always returns a `None` type object.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `re.search()` instead of `re.match()`.

`re.match()` only checks if the string exactly matches the RegExp, so if there's anything in the beginning that is unexpected, it's going to fail.